# Пустой результат при запросе с русскими символами в условии WHERE

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea, select, jdbc

Подключаюсь к базе MySQL из кода на Java через JDBC. При выполнении запроса:

```
select * from users
```

данные приходят нормально. 
При запросе:

```
select * from users where login='Ivan4'
```

также результат правильный.

Но если запрос с русскими символами, например:

```
select * from users where name='Петров'`
```

то результат пустой.

Почему так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте изменить параметры подключения

```
jdbc:mysql://host:port/dbName?characterEncoding=utf8
```

Comment: Да, с параметром код java вернул результат! Спасибо! Может быть вы еще знаете как настроить DB Navigator?

Comment: Если там тоже можно прямо вводить URL БД то скорее всего это же решение работает

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте выполнить

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

и еще попробуйте после этого добавить что-то на русском, а затем опять пробуйте свой запрос

Comment: таблицы в базе уже имеют формат utf8_general_ci. Но запрос выполнил. В саму базу через web интерфейс все добавляется. Через код java и через панель DB Navigator запросы результат не возвращают...